# Android 7.0 Nouget Webview can't show all images

Tags: android, android-webview, android-7.0-nougat

When I load a url in "Android 7.0",there are some images showing correctly but some images whose url is correct are blank in the emulator.All these images can show correctly in "Android 6.0". This is the code:

```
webview = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(false);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MJavascriptInterface(this,imageUrls), "imagelistener");
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webview.loadUrl(urlStr);
```

Comment: try to add other possible options for webview like setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true), setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true) , setAllowContentAccess(true) , setAppCacheEnabled(true)  and others as well. See if it works

Comment: `urlStr`. Is that the url for a html page? Or the url for one image only? Unclear.

Comment: Thanks.They don't work.@Stallion."urlStr" is for a html page which contains characters , images,videos and so on. @greenapps . I'm wondering if the page has too many images?

Comment: I wonder why you just dont post an url for such a html page. So that we could check.

Comment: `I'm wondering if the page has too many images?`. How would we know? You are the only one who knows how many images. But why don't you test a page with only one image?

Comment: `but some images whose url is correct are blank in the emulator`. Emulator? Better use a real device!

Comment: Please post a URL that can be used to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Try to create a different emulator skin with diff configuration. Or go for Genymotion. Best way is to test it on real device.

Comment: Thank you ,guys.@greenapps,@CommonsWare,@albeee.Maybe I find the problem.The page is normal when there is only one image.However,the page will take up a lot of memory when there are so many images.In the meantime ,the webview widget is just a chidview in my Activity and a lot of childviews are grouped into my activity. it means system will recycle image's memory when it thinks there is no full of memory. I can not find a real device of Nougat nearby.I cann't know why Nougat take up much more memory than Marshmallow ,  Although I can try to explain to myself that the problem is owing to memory.